# Python Dataframe categorize values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data coming from the field and I want to categorize it with a gap of specific range.
I want to categorize in 100 range. That is, 0-100, 100-200, 200-300
My code:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([112,341,234,78,154],columns=['value'])

    value
0   112
1   341
2   234
3   78
4   154
```

Expected answer:

```
    value  value_range
0   112    100-200
1   341    200-400
2   234    200-300
3   78     0-100
4   154    100-200
```

My code:

```
df['value_range'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x:[a,b] if x>a and x<b for a,b in zip([0,100,200,300,400],[100,200,300,400,500]))
```

Present solution:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pd.cut`:

```py
df["value_range"] = pd.cut(df["value"], [0, 100, 200, 300, 400], labels=['0-100', '100-200', '200-300', '300-400'])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   value value_range
0    112     100-200
1    341     300-400
2    234     200-300
3     78       0-100
4    154     100-200
```

Comment: This is a gem answer and you nailed it with this direct method. I never heard of it. I am only getting curious. Don't mind, can you tell me how and when did you come to know there is this method called `pd.cut`? Did you just learn, and practice all the methods that pandas offer and that's how you know them?

Comment: @Mainland Yes, it's just practice (answering question here on SO and in the job). But yeah, `pd.cut` its one of advanced methods of pandas.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the odd IntervalIndex.from_tuples.  Just set the tuple values to the values that are in your data and you should be good to go!  -Listen to Lil Wayne

```
df = pd.DataFrame([112,341,234,78,154],columns=['value'])

bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(0, 100), (100, 200), (200, 300), (300, 400)])
df['value_range'] = pd.cut(df['value'], bins)
```

[image: final df]